# Radio button event executing two times

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project, There are two radioButtons. To which I have given same `CheckedChanged` event by doing 
something like this:

```
DoctorRadioButton.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RadioButton_CheckedChanged);
PatientRadioButton.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RadioButton_CheckedChanged);
```

I kept both the RadioButtons in a `Panel` to make them one true while other one is false.
Now the problem is that I am implementing a very big code in the `RadioButton_CheckedChanged` event.
Whenever the user is changing the state of any of the two RadioButtons, the event is raising two times. 
After so many hours I got the answer, the event is raising two times because both the RadioButton states are being changed(Hence, the event will be raised two times). To solve this problem I am trying to unhook the event temporarily something like this:

**RadioButton_CheckedChanged** Event: (*Not Working*)

```
     if (DoctorRadioButton.Checked)
     {
         PatientRadioButton.CheckedChanged -= RadioButton_CheckedChanged; //Un
         //
         //My functions       
         //
         PatientRadioButton.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RadioButton_CheckedChanged);
     }
     else
     {
         DoctorRadioButton.CheckedChanged -= RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
         //
         //My functions         
         //
         DoctorRadioButton.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RadioButton_CheckedChanged);
     }
```

Eventhough the event is executing two times. I know I am doing something wrong in Hooking and Unhooking. Please Help.

Comment: Can't you put check of sender checkBox and do your work instead?

Comment: I dont know how to do that..

Comment: @RV1987 can you please help me how to do that?

Comment: Check answer if this is what you want.

Comment: I also have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You can check the sender RadioButton and place your code accordingly like this -

```
    void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton senderRadioButton = sender as RadioButton;
        if (senderRadioButton.Equals(DoctorRadioButton))
        // OR senderRadioButton.Name == "DoctorRadioButton"
        {
            // Place your code here for DoctorRadioButton.
        }
        else
        {
            // Place your code here for PatientRadioButton.
        }
    }
```

**Update**

If you can't use two different handlers for both radioButtons and want to execute code only in case checkbox is checked you can do this -

```
    void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton senderRadioButton = sender as RadioButton;
        if (senderRadioButton.IsChecked)
        {
            // Place your code here for check event.
        }
    }
```

Comment: nope still same (twice)... one is checking (invokes RadioButton checked changed event) at the same time other one is unchecking (invokes RadioButton checked changed event).

Comment: Yeah it will be called twice but can't you modify the code to place in two if blocks depending on the condition?

Comment: hmmm you mean `if(rb1.Checked)//do something else//nothing` and `if(rb2.Checked)//do something else//nothing` in a single event.. right?

Comment: Yes :) but eventhough the event will be called twice.. ok, I can manage that using if else statements.. thank you. But still this question hasn't got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For an extremely simple (albeit crude) solution would be to *not* hook both the radio buttons, and hook only one of them to the handler: since checking one radio unchecks the other one, it would work as intended.

A more complicated way would be to use a backing property, like this:

```
class myForm
{
    private bool radioStatus = false; // depends on the default status of the radios
    private bool RadioStatus 
    {
        get{return radioStatus;} set {radioStatus = value; Checked_Changed();}
    }

    public myForm()
    {
    // Lambdas as handlers to keep code short.
    DoctorRadioButton.CheckedChanged += (s,args)=> 
        { if((s as RadioButton).Checked) RadioStatus = true; };
    PatientRadioButton.CheckedChanged += (s,args)=> 
        { if((s as RadioButton).Checked) RadioStatus = false; };
    }

    void Checked_Changed()
    {
        if (RadioStatus) // = true --> DoctorRadioButton was checked
        {
            //code
        }
        else // = false --> PatientRadioButton was checked
        {
            //other code
        }
    }
}
```

This approach has the advantage of allowing you to abstract from the UI a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Put both radio buttons in the same panel or groupbox and automatically they will be grouped so that only one can be selected at a time.

Comment: ah ok, calling the event twice is the normal behavior here I guess since you are calling the event inside the event, that's why

Answer (score -1):

Its a late solution but i found there is no correct answer for your question so i am posting it may be it works For You

*Create Click Event for both radio button and simple put your code beacuse on every click your radio button got checked and your code executes* :):):)

```
private void DoctorRadioButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Your code on Doctor Radio Button
        }

private void PatientRadioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Your code on Patient Radio Button
        }
```